# The Case of the Missing Rebus

Tags: pattern, rebus

A rebus has gone missing.    What rebus, and under which
$~\boxed{\sf~ \raise{.5ex}\underline\quad \, ? ~\raise{.1ex}\strut}$ ?

$$ \color{#274}{\boxed{ \quad \begin{matrix}                         \\[-1ex]
& \kern-1em \rm ADAD & & \raise{2.5ex}\strut
\kern-2em\raise{1.2ex}\color{black}{\boxed{\sf~ here? ~\raise{.1ex}\strut}} \\[-1ex]
& \kern-1em \rm ADAD & & & & \kern-1em\rm LLL                        \\[-1ex]
&                    & & & & \kern-1em\rm LLL & & \kern-1em x  \,  y \\[-1ex]
&                    & & & &                  & & \kern-1em z \:\: t \\[-1ex]
\rm XCXC &           & & & &                  & &                    \\[-1ex]
\rm XCXC &           & & & &                  & & & &
\kern-2em\raise{-2ex}\color{black}{\boxed{\sf~ perhaps? ~\raise{.1ex}\strut\raise{-.2ex}\strut}} \\[-1ex]
& & \kern-2em\raise{1.4ex}\color{black}{\boxed{\sf~ maybe? ~\raise{.1ex}\strut\raise{-.2ex}\strut}}
    & & \kern-1em\rm TTT & &                                         \\[-1ex]
& & & & \kern-1em\rm TTT & &
\kern-1em\raise{-1.2ex}\color{black}{\boxed{\sf~ or? ~\raise{.1ex}\strut}} \\[-1ex]
& & & & & & & &                           & & & \kern-1em\rm Sn      \\[-1ex]
& & & & & & & &\kern-1em ~ 2e/6           & & & \kern-1em\rm Sn      \\[0ex]
& & & & & & & &\kern-1em e/2 {-} \!\; e/6 & &                        \\[-1ex]
& & & & & & & &                           & & \kern-1em\rm TT        \\[-1ex]
& & & & & & & &                           & & & & \kern-1em\rm ZZZZZ \\[-1ex]
& & & & & & & &   \raise{-1.7ex}\strut    & & & & \kern-1em\rm ZZZZZ \\
\end{matrix} \quad }} $$

Naturally, the answer may be rebused more than one way.

Nothing is under three of the
$~\raise{-1.2ex}{^{^\boxed{\sf~ \raise{.5ex}\underline\quad \, ? ~\raise{.1ex}\strut}}}~\!$s.
 
Hint from a comment:

> The clues
>  $\rm\raise{-.3ex}{\color{#274}{~ \atop TT}}$
>  and
>  $\rm\raise{2.3ex}{\color{#274}{\raise{-.5ex}{Sn} \atop Sn}}$
>  lead to stereotypical New Zealand pronunciations.

Comment: Hello. "Rebused" rhymes with "bemused" in my head. Thanks and have a good day.

Comment: @question_asker Do you wish to report domestic rebuse?

Comment: @samthere that's a little tasteless

Comment: That's some serious MathJax!

Comment: am i right with 'my two dads' and 'tintin'?

Comment: The possible interpretation "$\text{A DAD}\!\;$" is a red herring. Something about $\rm Sn$ has been hintified above.

Comment: @hmmn I'm a little confused so I'm going to [invite you to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37168/hmmn-and-question-asker-chatting-about-square-roots)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The missing rebus is:

> **TTT T TTT** or anything else that gives **seventies**

And it needs to be positioned under the box labelled:

> **maybe?**

---

**Reasoning**:

> Reading from left to right, ignoring vertical position, we have:
>
>  **XCXC XCXC** - XC is Roman numeral for 90, and there's multiple, so we've got **nineties**
>  **ADAD ADAD** - a plurality of *ADs* or **eighties**
>  *...the missing one needs to go in here...*
>  **TTT TTT** - *six Ts*, or **sixties**
>  **LLL LLL** - similarly with Roman numeral *50s* gives **fifties**
>  **xy z t** - the four dimensions, or *4Ds*, giving **forties**
>  **2e/6 e/2−e/6** - both equations resolve to *a third of e*, but there's two, so we get *third es* or **thirties**
>  **TT** - *twin Ts*, or (again with an NZ accent) **twenties**
>  **Sn Sn** - Sn is the chemical symbol for Tin, and we've got more than one, giving us *Tins*, or (putting on our NZ accent) **tens**
>  **ZZZZZ ZZZZZ** - we've got two rows of Zs, or *Z rows*, giving **zeroes**

However, the above solution leaves two possible positions that the missing rebus could appear in:

> **maybe?** or **here?**
>
>  But, if we consider the derebussed words in order of height in the graph, we get:
>
>  *here?*
>  **eighties**
>  **fifties**
>  **forties**
>  **nineties**
>  *maybe?*
>  **sixties**
>  **tens**
>  **thirties**
>  **twenties**
>  **zeroes**
>
>  It should be painfully obvious, even to the most dimwitted of individuals*, that the words are in alphabetical order... Thus **seventies**, must be hidden under **maybe?** to complete the pattern.

<sub><sub>* I stared at the list for quite some time before realising</sub></sub>

Comment: @hmmn - I notice that the overall graph is decade decayed, but that doesn't help with the positioning...

Comment: @humn - ok, finished now. I'm sure I wrote them out in that order previously, but perhaps I only did so with the symbols rather than the words... (Excellent puzzle by the way).

Answer (score 3):

**Wrap-up: the making of
[*The Case of the
  Missing Rebus*](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28885)**

*This is not a solution to the puzzle but provides notes from its poser.
 This type of answer has been
 [approved by the community](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5420/).*

***Caution:** This post contains information about the solution.*

---

Often (almost always?) construction of a puzzle presents
a more challenging puzzle than does the resultant puzzle.
Sometimes the puzzle of construction itself
can neatly infect the finished puzzle.

In this case, leaving a part of the puzzle incomplete improved it.
The original idea was a two-dimensional pattern of rebuses
whose numerical and verbal interpretations
were distractions from each other,
for a [Stroop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stroop_effect)-like effect.
This would’ve been acceptable for posting,
with multiple clues from two angles,
but 3 rebuses remained to concoct
with only enough ideas for 2 of them.

$$ \kern-2em \small \color{#274}{\boxed{ \quad \begin{matrix}             \\[-1ex]
& \kern -4em\raise2ex\color {black}{\boxed{\matrix{\sf \raise.4ex{same}\\[-1ex] \sf \raise.4ex{2~ideas}} }}
                     & & & \kern-1em\rm LLL                               \\[-1ex]
&                    & & & \kern-1em\rm LLL & & \kern-1em x  \,  y        \\[-1ex]
&                    & & &                  & & \kern-1em z \:\: t        \\[-1ex]
\rm XCXC &           & & &                  & &                           \\[-1ex]
\rm XCXC &
             \raise -2ex\color {black}{\boxed {\matrix{\sf\raise .4ex{same}\\[-1ex] \sf\raise .4ex{2~ideas}} }}
  & \kern-1em \raise-5ex \color{black}{ \boxed{\matrix{ \sf\raise.4ex{same} \\[-1ex] \sf\raise.4ex{2~ideas}} }}\kern-2em
    & & & & &                           & & & \kern-1em\raise-8ex{\rm Sn} \\[-.6ex]
& & & & & & &\kern-1em ~ 2e/6           & & & \kern-1em           \rm Sn  \\[0ex]
& & & & & & &\kern-1em e/2 {-} \!\; e/6 & &                               \\[-1ex]
& & & & & & &                           & & \kern-1em\rm TT               \\[-1ex]
& & & & & & &                           & & & & \kern-1em\rm ZZZZZ        \\[-1ex]
& & & & & & &   \raise{-1.7ex}\strut    & & & & \kern-1em\rm ZZZZZ        \\
\end{matrix} \quad }} $$

💡
So why not just be lazy and leave one rebus blank,
as the pattern is well established without it,
and direct the challenge toward filling it in?
This would have serendipitous benefits.

  •   
    Add meaning to solving the originally conceived puzzle.

  •   
    Specify the challenge more precisely
    than “what’s going on here?”

  •   
    Provide an opportunity,
    with ready examples but no pressure,
    for solvers to be inventive.

💡💡
Aesthetically unsatisfying gaps in the midst of the layout
could also be filled in with possible places
where the missing rebus might belong.
This had a surprise benefit as well.

  •   
    The numerical and verbal patterns
    must be explicitly solved, not merely sensed.

These 💡💡💡
added natural levels atop a puzzle
that already had nine mini-puzzles
by which to gather momentum while solving.

Comment: Do these NZ-pronounced words frequently appear in *common, simple* puzzles, like a crossword, or a wordsearch? Are they well-known variants for the other (outside of NZ) native English speakers?

Comment: The TT rebus felt cheap at the time too, thus the NZ hint. My justification was that it had been used in a USA rebus TV show (truly authoritative!) and that the NZ number-pronunciation guide I found included it as an example. Different rebuses here were expected to have different degrees of transparency so that whichever turned out to be less obvious would be more likely solved in reverse, to reinforce a suspected pattern after the more-obvious rebuses were solved.