# Dragons: Myth or MathJax?

Tags: mathematics, visual, computer-puzzle, mathjax

**E**ver use MathJax to display mathematical expressions?
 
Expressions related to fractals?


Ever used it to display fractals themselves?!
 
The time has come.

[image]

These fractals are based on the iconic
[dragon curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_curve)
and raise two questions.

1. **What is the rule behind these arrangements of letters?**
   A clear description,
   *or* just a MathJax demonstration of the first 7 levels,
   would merit a vote of approval.
2. **What is the highest level that
    MathJax can produce within its default limits?**
   To demonstrate a solution, the first 7 levels should be rendered
   live by the answer
   but, for the sake of expedient presentation,
   higher levels should be represented by images.
   In test-solving this puzzle,
   getting past level 12 involved cheating
   the default “maximum macro substitution count.”
   Just to get past level 8 without cheating
   required a new round of creativity
   and longer code.
   Default limits at post time: 
   $\scriptsize\texttt{MathJax.Hub.Config({TeX:{MAXBUFFER:5120, MAXMACROS:10000}})}$

Only the letters and their alignment,
not their font or spacing,
need to match the examples above.
No need to produce multiple levels in a single call,
or even in a single MathJax block.
No need to label the levels
or to arrange them in any particular formation.
Code minimality, in this puzzle, is just an informal consideration
for discriminating between multiple solutions if they reach the same level.

<sub>**MathJax incidentals**


Please practice safe MathJax by using $\texttt{\begingroup} \raise1.7ex\strut$
and $\texttt{\endgroup}$.
The following template is good for this:</sub>

```
      $ \require{begingroup} \begingroup   \def \safe {\text{\endgroup error}} $

      (Answer that contains MathJax blocks)

      $ \endgroup \safe $
```

<sub>If all goes well, the answer will end with
(as in the image above):
$~~~~~~~~~~~~\bbox[mistyrose]{\color{red}{\text{\safe}}} \raise-.8ex\strut$


If
$\texttt{\endgroup}$ is not used successfully,
the template is meant to show:
$~~\text{\endgroup error} \raise-.8ex\strut$


Before posting an answer, be sure to test it
on a freshly loaded browser page.
Might also need to reload the page while editing,
as inadvertent indiscretions in one edit
can pervert MathJax results during later edits.</sub>

**See also**   (feel free to add)

[Other puzzles tagged](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathjax) [mathjax](/questions/tagged/mathjax)

[Defining macros in MathJax](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/v2.5-latest/tex.html#defining-tex-macros)

[$\sf\scriptsize \raise2mu( L \kern-2mu \raise4mu{\tiny A} \kern0mu \raise2mu) {\scriptsize T} \kern-1mu \raise-4mu E \kern1mu X$ commands in MathJax](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/v2.5-latest/tex.html#supported-latex-commands)

[$\sf\scriptsize {\scriptsize T} \kern-1mu \raise-4mu E \kern1mu X$ commands available in MathJax](http://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm)

[MathJax reference at Mathematics Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

[MathJax questions at Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathjax)
|
[Physics Meta](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathjax)
|
[Puzzling Meta](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathjax)
|
[Mathematics Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathjax)

Comment: I'm a little confused about the starting conditions.  Is the code suppose to produce *all* the levels, or does it take a given level (serialized) and produce the next?  Are the "level x" labels part of the requirement?

Comment: Yeh, the wording was rushed originally and is a little clearer now.
Also, this puzzle seemed complicated enough without
code minimality as a formal goal.

Comment: Have you tried to pitch this at Code Golf? It might be a better fit there.

Comment: Admittedly this treads the line here, @Emrakul, but it's too language-specific for Code Golf. (They've even [rejected testable native code](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5056/do-we-really-want-latex-mathjax-right-now).) I did mention a previous MathJax puzzle in their chat room and got no response. Also, half of this puzzle is figuring out the fractal.

Comment: Thanks, @humn, that makes things clearer.  Now I understand your separation of the `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` into separate math delimiters.  You can do each level separately in a new expression (taking advantage of previous definitions, and since each expression resets the MAXBUFFER and MAXMACROS settings, each level will have its own limits.  Got it.

Comment: When you give the "default limits" above, do you mean the ones you used, or the ones in place on SE?  If the latter, they are 5120 (not 9120) and 10000 (not 20000), so I wasn't sure.  Also, were you able to produce level 12 within the default limits, or did that require a change?  The L-R string for level 12 is 2731 characters, so fits within the buffer size, but if each character is handled separately (as in my code), then that would mean that it would have to be done in an average of 3.7 macro calls per letter.  I don't think I can get it down that far.

Comment: Relieved to say, @Davide C, my level 12 does legitimately use
the default (5120/10000?) limits
and calls exactly the same count of 2731 letters you mention.
I don't see anything per letter that I'm doing more efficiently
and I'm certainly placing letters wayyyyyyy less efficiently,
compounding ~20 custom macro calls per letter that don't seem to count
against the limit.
The only place my code might be simpler
is in the recursive definition,
which isn't as elegant mathematically
but does avoid reversal.
Forever I thought of linear dragons in terms of reversal,
before this puzzle.

Comment: I'm not at all into MathJax, but I do like the "figure out what the dragon is" part of this puzzle. +1 for that.

Comment: I'll be curious to see what your code looks like, @humn, and how it avoids the MAXMACROS substitution limit.  Of course, I am also curious about the non-reversal approach to the dragons as well (maybe keeping track of a reversed sequence as well as the forward one?), which I haven't solved, but also haven't taken much time to consider.

Comment: Possibly unnecessary almost-hint on the non-reversing generation rule: Its essence was recognized during hand tracing of the standard dragon curve..

Comment: I think I know why you are not hitting the MAXMACROS limitation, and I know how to exploit it to allow for creating much larger levels without having to change the limits.  On the other hand, that does mean there is a way to get around the limits that probably should be considered a bug in MathJax.  So I may have to fix it (and so break my new solution to creating larger levels).  But at least for now, I can make bigger fractals without resetting the macro count. I'll try to post an updated solution tomorrow (I only have proof of concept done tonight).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Answer to Part 1

> We encode a dragon, $D$, as a string of $L$s and $R$s, where we start facing right and place the first letter at our starting point.  If it is an $L$, we turn left and move forward one space; if it is an $R$ turn right and move forward one space.  Then place the second letter, and repeat the process until the string of letters is used up.
>
> Given a dragon, $D$, we write $\overline D$ to mean the dragon obtained from $D$ by replacing all its $L$s with $R$s and *vice versa*. We write $\neg D$ to represent the dragon whose string of letters is the string for $D$ listed in reverse. Finally, for two dragons, $D$ and $D'$, we write $DD'$ to mean the dragon whose string is the concatenation of the strings for $D$ and $D'$, in that order.
>
> Let $D_i$ represent the level $i$ dragon, and take $D_1 = R$ and $D_2 = LRR$.  Then $D_i$ (for $i\ge3$) is obtained by $(\neg\overline{D_{i-2}})\, D_{i-1}\, D_{i-2}$.

---

### Answer to Part 2

This is an updated solution to part 2.  It produces all the dragons through level 19 without needing to adjust the MathJax parameters, though the later levels take quite a long time to produce, and are beginning to push the limits of the browser itself to display the result (for levels past 15 or so, I have to wait a while for the browser to update when I scroll the page).  Printing the page to PDF (in order to make the images) turned out to take as log as MathJax generating the picture in the first place.  So although the technique I used theoretically could be extended to go to even larger dragons, it probably isn't practical to do so.

I employ a trick to get around MathJax's macro-substitution limit that currently is a "feature" of MathJax, but should probably be fixed, so these examples may not work in the future if that occurs.  The idea is that each expression typeset by MathJax gets its own parsing environment, and with it its own copy of the buffer and macro limits; some actions in MathJax introduce such parsing environments automatically, and this can be used to get additional macro substitutions.  One such place is using mathematics within a `\text{}` macro, so the inner expression in `\text{$...$}` will have its own 5120 macro substitutions, regardless of the number that have already been performed outside the `\text{}` call.

We use this by breaking up the Dragon into pieces: taking advantage of the fact that $D_k = (\neg \overline D_{k-2})D_{k-1}D_{k-2}$, we can draw the three pieces $\neg\overline D_{k-2}$, $D_{k-1}$, and $D_{k-2}$ separately, each in its on expression, to get three times as many macro substitutions as we would if we tried to do them all in one expression.  Larger dragons can be handled by chaining together more parts.  By hooking together more and more pieces we can get to level 20 before running into the maximum buffer size for the parts.  These are produced by the `\BigDragon` macro (and the `\NextBigDragon` macro) below.

Of course, we could then do the same trick again to set up an extra big dragon (`\BiggDragon`?) to get up to level 30, but level 19 is already pushing the limits of the browser, so that seems impractical.  It would also require improving the addition and subtraction macros to use 4-digit numbers rather than the current 3-digit ones.  Although the current version can handle level 20 in terms of macro substitutions, it also requires the 4-digit numbers, so that is why the code below only goes to 19.

I have put some comments in the code (listed after the diagrams below), but don't have time to write anything more about it at the moment.  I think it should be pretty straight forward.

It is best to use the PreviewHTML output for MathJax rather than the HTML-CSS output, since this will be much faster.  To switch, right-click (or CTRL-click) on any typeset math, and select the "Math Settings" menu, then the "Math Renderer" submenu, then the "Preview HTML" output.  I'd also turn off the "Fast Preview", and the "Assistive MathML" options for best results.

$\require{begingroup}\begingroup \def\safe{\text{\endgroup error}}$
$
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%  Some utility functions:
%
%
%  Make a large rectangle to surround the dragon.
%
\def\Board#1#2{\bbox[border:1px solid black]{\xspace{#1}\Rule{0em}{#2em}{0em}}}
%
%  Place a letter at the right location on the board.
%
\def\Place#1#2#3{\smash{\rlap{\xspace{#1}\raise{#2em}{#3}}}}
%
%  Do the horizontal space (the letters are a bit bigger than an ex at 
%  \small size, so add extra space via pts).
%
\def\init{\sf\small}
\def\xspace#1{\hskip #1ex\hskip #1pt \hskip #1pt \hskip #1pt}
%\def\init{\sf\tiny}           %  for \BigDragons, use these two lines
%\def\xspace#1{\hskip #1ex}    %    and comment out the previous two
%
%  Place a marker with a given color at the correct place.
%
\def\Marker#1#2#3{\Place{#2}{#3}{\color{#1}{\kern-2.25pt\raise.25pt\bigcirc}}} % for \small
%\def\Marker#1#2#3{\Place{#2}{#3}{\color{#1}{\kern-1.25pt\raise2pt\bigcirc}}}    % for \tiny
\def\Marker#1#2#3{} % don't put in markers -- comment out to show them
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%  Create a dragon from the currently saved dragon string starting
%    at the given location on the board, or a big dragon from
%    the last big dragon collections.
%
\def\Dragon#1#2{\Start{#1}{#2}\E \Continue\Db \End}
\def\BigDragon#1#2{\Start{#1}{#2}\E \Bq{}\Bb{}\Ba{} \End}
%
%  Check if there are more letters and call \P if so and \X if not.
%
\def\D#1 #2#3 #4{#4#1 #2#3 #4}
%
%  Place the letter at the current location.
%  Then define \T to determine the new orientation from
%    the current one and the current letter.
%  Perform the orientation command in order to move to the new location.
%
\def\P#1#2#3#4{
  \Place{#1}{#2}#4
  \def\T##1#4#3 ##2##3\T{##2{#1}{#2}##2 }
  \T L\E \N  R\E \S  L\S \E  R\S \W  L\W \S  R\W \N  L\N \W  R\N \E  \T
}
%
%  These are the commands to move in the given direction.
%
\def\N#1#2{\def\n##1##2##3{\D{#1}{##1##2##3}}\p\n#2}
\def\E#1#2{\def\n##1##2##3{\D{##1##2##3}{#2}}\p\n#1}
\def\S#1#2{\def\n##1##2##3{\D{#1}{##1##2##3}}\m\n#2}
\def\W#1#2{\def\n##1##2##3{\D{##1##2##3}{#2}}\m\n#1}
%
%  Routines to add or subtract (plus or minus) 1 from
%    a three-digit number, so we can handle 000 to 999.
%    These roll over if they go too far.
%
\def\p#1#2#3#4{
  \def\:##1#4##2##3 ##4#4 ##5##6\:{##5#1#2#3##2}
  \: 01234567890 9 \pp #4 {} \:
}
\def\pp#1#2#3{\p\drop0#2#3#1}
\def\m#1#2#3#4{
  \def\:##1#4##2##3 ##4#4 ##5##6\:{##5#1#2#3##2}
  \: 98765432109 0 \mm #4 {} \:
}
\def\mm#1#2#3{\m\drop9#2#3#1}
\def\drop#1#2#3#4{#4#2#3}
%
%  Start a dragon by placing a marker and creating the \Continue function.
%  End a dragon by continuing with the end marker, cleaning up, and then 
%    placing the board boundary.
%  
\def\Start#1#2#3{\init\Marker{green}{#1}{#2}\X{#1}{#2}#3\X}
\def\End{\C\EndMarker\Board}
\def\EndMarker#1#2\X{\EndPlace#1}
\def\EndPlace#1#2#3#4{\Marker{red}{#2}{#3}}
%
%  End the current portion of the dragon by defining a continuation 
%    function that records the current location and orientation.
%    Each continuation is done in \text{$...$} so that it gets its own
%    equation environment with its own MAXMACROS and MAXBUFFER space.
%    This lets us do multiple pieces without exceeding the limitations.
%
\def\X#1#2#3#4\X{\def\C##1{\text{$\init ##1{\D{#1}{#2}#3} \P \X$}}\let\Continue=\C}
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%  These functions produce new dragons from old ones.
%  We keep a separate reversed copy so that we don't have
%  to reverse them later.
%
\def\NextDragon{\Next\Da\Db\Dq\Dr}
\def\NextBigDragon{\Next\Ba\Bb\Bq\Br}
\def\Next#1#2#3#4{
  #3\Copy\It #2\Copy\It #1\Copy\It \Define \EndD \tmpA
  #3\Copy\It #4\Copy\It #1\Copy\It \Define \EndD \tmpB
  \let#1=#2 \let#2=\tmpA
  \let#3=#4 \let#4=\tmpB
  \def\tmpA{} \let\tmpB=\tmpA
}
\def\Define#1\EndD#2{\def#2##1{##1 #1}}
\def\Copy#1\It#2\EndD{#2#1\EndD}
%
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%  The initial two dragons (D_0 and D_1) and their reversed versions,
%  and the initial two Big Dragons, based on them.  Big Dragons use
%  \C (\Continue) to do multiple pieces (based on the largest small
%  Dragon that can be processed within the MathJax limits).
%
\def\Da#1{#1 R} \let\Db=\Da
\def\Dq#1{#1 L} \let\Dr=\Dq
%
\def\Ba#1{#1 \C\Da} \def\Bb#1{#1 \C\Db}
\def\Bq#1{#1 \C\Dq} \def\Br#1{#1 \C\Dr}
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
$

$\Dragon{002}{002} {5}{5}$
$\NextDragon\Dragon{002}{002} {6}{6}$
$\NextDragon\Dragon{003}{002} {6}{7}$
$\NextDragon\Dragon{005}{002} {8}{8}$
$\NextDragon\Dragon{007}{004} {10}{9}$

$\NextDragon\Dragon{009}{007} {12}{12}$
$\NextDragon\Dragon{007}{012} {13}{16}$

Some links to larger dragons:

- [Level 8 dragon curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKqap.png)
- [Level 9 dragon curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcKSO.png)
- [Level 10 dragon curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dbvv.png)
- [Level 11 dragon curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vbCM.png)
- [Level 12 dragon curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvYMp.png)
- [Level 13 dragon curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxDvo.png)
- [Level 14 dragon curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7VMH.png)
- [Level 15 dragon curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLonu.jpg)
- [Level 16 dragon curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJVFp.jpg)
- [Level 17 dragon curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BS4Jv.jpg)
- [Level 18 dragon curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wXs2.jpg)

This is the largest that I've made (the level 19 dragon):

[image: Level 19 dragon curve]

$\endgroup\safe$

The code:

```
$\require{begingroup}\begingroup \def\safe{\text{\endgroup error}}$
$
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%  Some utility functions:
%
%
%  Make a large rectangle to surround the dragon.
%
\def\Board#1#2{\bbox[border:1px solid black]{\xspace{#1}\Rule{0em}{#2em}{0em}}}
%
%  Place a letter at the right location on the board.
%
\def\Place#1#2#3{\smash{\rlap{\xspace{#1}\raise{#2em}{#3}}}}
%
%  Do the horizontal space (the letters are a bit bigger than an ex at 
%  \small size, so add extra space via pts).
%
\def\init{\sf\small}
\def\xspace#1{\hskip #1ex\hskip #1pt \hskip #1pt \hskip #1pt}
%\def\init{\sf\tiny}           %  for \BigDragons, use these two lines
%\def\xspace#1{\hskip #1ex}    %    and comment out the previous two
%
%  Place a marker with a given color at the correct place.
%
\def\Marker#1#2#3{\Place{#2}{#3}{\color{#1}{\kern-2.25pt\raise.25pt\bigcirc}}} % for \small
%\def\Marker#1#2#3{\Place{#2}{#3}{\color{#1}{\kern-1.25pt\raise2pt\bigcirc}}}    % for \tiny
\def\Marker#1#2#3{} % don't put in markers -- comment out to show them
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%  Create a dragon from the currently saved dragon string starting
%    at the given location on the board, or a big dragon from
%    the last big dragon collections.
%
\def\Dragon#1#2{\Start{#1}{#2}\E \Continue\Db \End}
\def\BigDragon#1#2{\Start{#1}{#2}\E \Bq{}\Bb{}\Ba{} \End}
%
%  Check if there are more letters and call \P if so and \X if not.
%
\def\D#1 #2#3 #4{#4#1 #2#3 #4}
%
%  Place the letter at the current location.
%  Then define \T to determine the new orientation from
%    the current one and the current letter.
%  Perform the orientation command in order to move to the new location.
%
\def\P#1#2#3#4{
  \Place{#1}{#2}#4
  \def\T##1#4#3 ##2##3\T{##2{#1}{#2}##2 }
  \T L\E \N  R\E \S  L\S \E  R\S \W  L\W \S  R\W \N  L\N \W  R\N \E  \T
}
%
%  These are the commands to move in the given direction.
%
\def\N#1#2{\def\n##1##2##3{\D{#1}{##1##2##3}}\p\n#2}
\def\E#1#2{\def\n##1##2##3{\D{##1##2##3}{#2}}\p\n#1}
\def\S#1#2{\def\n##1##2##3{\D{#1}{##1##2##3}}\m\n#2}
\def\W#1#2{\def\n##1##2##3{\D{##1##2##3}{#2}}\m\n#1}
%
%  Routines to add or subtract (plus or minus) 1 from
%    a three-digit number, so we can handle 000 to 999.
%    These roll over if they go too far.
%
\def\p#1#2#3#4{
  \def\:##1#4##2##3 ##4#4 ##5##6\:{##5#1#2#3##2}
  \: 01234567890 9 \pp #4 {} \:
}
\def\pp#1#2#3{\p\drop0#2#3#1}
\def\m#1#2#3#4{
  \def\:##1#4##2##3 ##4#4 ##5##6\:{##5#1#2#3##2}
  \: 98765432109 0 \mm #4 {} \:
}
\def\mm#1#2#3{\m\drop9#2#3#1}
\def\drop#1#2#3#4{#4#2#3}
%
%  Start a dragon by placing a marker and creating the \Continue function.
%  End a dragon by continuing with the end marker, cleaning up, and then 
%    placing the board boundary.
%  
\def\Start#1#2#3{\init\Marker{green}{#1}{#2}\X{#1}{#2}#3\X}
\def\End{\C\EndMarker\Board}
\def\EndMarker#1#2\X{\EndPlace#1}
\def\EndPlace#1#2#3#4{\Marker{red}{#2}{#3}}
%
%  End the current portion of the dragon by defining a continuation 
%    function that records the current location and orientation.
%    Each continuation is done in \text{$...$} so that it gets its own
%    equation environment with its own MAXMACROS and MAXBUFFER space.
%    This lets us do multiple pieces without exceeding the limitations.
%
\def\X#1#2#3#4\X{\def\C##1{\text{$\init ##1{\D{#1}{#2}#3} \P \X$}}\let\Continue=\C}
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%  These functions produce new dragons from old ones.
%  We keep a separate reversed copy so that we don't have
%  to reverse them later.
%
\def\NextDragon{\Next\Da\Db\Dq\Dr}
\def\NextBigDragon{\Next\Ba\Bb\Bq\Br}
\def\Next#1#2#3#4{
  #3\Copy\It #2\Copy\It #1\Copy\It \Define \EndD \tmpA
  #3\Copy\It #4\Copy\It #1\Copy\It \Define \EndD \tmpB
  \let#1=#2 \let#2=\tmpA
  \let#3=#4 \let#4=\tmpB
  \def\tmpA{} \let\tmpB=\tmpA
}
\def\Define#1\EndD#2{\def#2##1{##1 #1}}
\def\Copy#1\It#2\EndD{#2#1\EndD}
%
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%  The initial two dragons (D_0 and D_1) and their reversed versions,
%  and the initial two Big Dragons, based on them.  Big Dragons use
%  \C (\Continue) to do multiple pieces (based on the largest small
%  Dragon that can be processed within the MathJax limits).
%
\def\Da#1{#1 R} \let\Db=\Da
\def\Dq#1{#1 L} \let\Dr=\Dq
%
\def\Ba#1{#1 \C\Da} \def\Bb#1{#1 \C\Db}
\def\Bq#1{#1 \C\Dq} \def\Br#1{#1 \C\Dr}
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
$

$\Dragon{002}{002} {5}{5} % Level 1 $
$\NextDragon\Dragon{002}{002} {6}{6} % Level 2 $
$\NextDragon\Dragon{003}{002} {6}{7} % Level 3 $
$\NextDragon\Dragon{005}{002} {8}{8} % Level 4 $
$\NextDragon\Dragon{007}{004} {10}{9} % Level 5 $
<br/>
$\NextDragon\Dragon{009}{007} {12}{12} % Level 6 $
$\NextDragon\Dragon{007}{012} {13}{16} % Level 7 $
$\NextDragon\Dragon{006}{015} {20}{20} % Level 8 $
<br/>
$\NextDragon\Dragon{006}{012} {28}{23} % Level 9 $
<br/>
$\NextDragon\Dragon{006}{010} {36}{36} % Level 10 $
<br/>
$\NextBigDragon$$\BigDragon{019}{009} {41}{52} % Level 11 $
<br/>
$\NextBigDragon$$\BigDragon{049}{010} {68}{68} % level 12 $
$\NextBigDragon$$\BigDragon{085}{036} {102}{79} % Level 13 $
$\NextBigDragon$$\BigDragon{113}{095} {132}{132} % Level 14 $
$\NextBigDragon$$\BigDragon{083}{164} {153}{196} % Level 15 $
$\NextBigDragon$$\BigDragon{071}{223} {262}{260} % Level 16 $
$\NextBigDragon$$\BigDragon{062}{164} {389}{302} % Level 17 $
$\NextBigDragon$$\BigDragon{071}{138} {518}{516} % Level 18 $
$\NextBigDragon$$\BigDragon{277}{121} {604}{771} % Level 19 $

$\endgroup\safe$
```

---

### Decorated Dragons

Rather than "L" and "R", I thought it would be nice to use actual corners, or the classical rounded corners, and a small change to the code allows for that.  Then I started to experiment with other ideas, like color.  The code below allows you to select one of several different corner types.  Simply include the macro that defines that type of corner and run the dragon.  These are best viewed in SVG output, though most work in CommonHTML as well.  PreviewHTML doesn't always work for these, unfortunately.

The following are all the level 14 dragon:

- Using `\Corners`

  [image: Level 14 dragon - angled corners]
- Using `\RoundCorners`

  [image: Level 14 dragon - rounded corners]
- Using `\TransparentBlocks`

  [image: Level 14 dragon - transparent colored blocks]
- Using `\Diagonals`

  [image: Level 14 dragon - diagonal corners]
- Using `\BlackTriangles`

  [image]
- Using `\OpenTriangles`

  [image]
- Using `\Paths`.

  [image]
- Using `\RedDots`.  This highlights the paths from one "side" of the dragon line.

  [image]
- Using `\RedBlueDots`.  This makes dotted paths along both sets of paths, one set colored red, the other blue.

  [image]

See the code for additional options, and try them out.

```
$
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%  Some utility functions:
%
%
%  Make a large rectangle to surround the dragon.
%
\def\Board#1#2{\bbox[border:1px solid black]{\hskip#1ex\Rule{0ex}{#2ex}{0ex}}}
%
%  Place a letter at the right location on the board.
%
\def\Place#1#2#3{\smash{\rlap{\hskip #1ex\raise{#2ex}{#3}}}}
%
%  Place a marker with a given color at the correct place.
%
%\def\Marker#1#2#3{\Place{#2}{#3}{\color{#1}{\kern-2.25pt\raise.25pt\bigcirc}}} % for \small
%\def\Marker#1#2#3{\Place{#2}{#3}{\color{#1}{\kern2.1pt\raise.5pt\bigcirc}}}    % for \tiny
\def\Marker#1#2#3{} % don't put in markers -- comment out to show them
%
%  The shape of the corners
%
\def\Corners{
  \def\SEs{\kern.47ex\Rule{.06ex}{.53ex}{0ex}\raise.47ex{\Rule{.47ex}{.06ex}{0ex}}}
  \def\SWs{\raise.47ex{\Rule{.47ex}{.06ex}{0ex}}\Rule{.06ex}{.53ex}{0ex}}
  \def\NEn{\kern.47ex\raise.47ex{\Rule{.06ex}{.53ex}{0ex}\Rule{.47ex}{.06ex}{0ex}}}
  \def\NWn{\raise.47ex{\Rule{.47ex}{.06ex}{0ex}\Rule{.06ex}{.53ex}{0ex}}}
  \let\SEe=\SEs \let\SWw=\SWs \let\NEe=\NEn \let\NWw=\NWn
}
\def\HalfBlocks{
  \def\SEs{\kern.47ex\Rule{.53ex}{.53ex}{0ex}}
  \def\SWs{\Rule{.53ex}{.53ex}{0ex}}
  \def\NEn{\kern.47ex\raise.47ex{\Rule{.53ex}{.53ex}{0ex}}}
  \def\NWn{\raise.47ex{\Rule{.53ex}{.53ex}{0ex}}}
  \let\SEe=\SEs \let\SWw=\SWs \let\NEe=\NEn \let\NWw=\NWn
}
\def\TransparentBlocks{
  \def\SEs{\style{opacity:.5}{\color{red}{\Rule{1ex}{1ex}{0ex}}}}
  \def\SWs{\style{opacity:.5}{\color{blue}{\Rule{1ex}{1ex}{0ex}}}}
  \def\NEn{\style{opacity:.5}{\color{green}{\Rule{1ex}{1ex}{0ex}}}}
  \def\NWn{\style{opacity:.5}{\color{orange}{\Rule{1ex}{1ex}{0ex}}}}
  \let\SEe=\SEs \let\SWw=\SWs \let\NEe=\NEn \let\NWw=\NWn
}
\def\RoundCorners{
  \def\SEs{\style{font-size:85%}{\unicode{x256D}}}
  \def\SWs{\style{font-size:85%}{\unicode{x256E}}}
  \def\NEn{\style{font-size:85%}{\unicode{x2570}}}
  \def\NWn{\style{font-size:85%}{\unicode{x256F}}}
  \let\SEe=\SEs \let\SWw=\SWs \let\NEe=\NEn \let\NWw=\NWn
}
\def\Diagonals{
  \def\SEs{\hskip.5ex\style{font-size:28%}{\unicode{x2571}}}
  \def\SWs{\style{font-size:28%}{\unicode{x2572}}}
  \def\NEn{\hskip.5ex\raise.5ex{\style{font-size:28%}{\unicode{x2572}}}}
  \def\NWn{\raise.5ex{\style{font-size:28%}{\unicode{x2571}}}}
  \let\SEe=\SEs \let\SWw=\SWs \let\NEe=\NEn \let\NWw=\NWn
}
\def\OpenTriangles{
  \def\SEs{\hskip.5ex\style{font-size:25%}{\unicode{x25FF}}}
  \def\SWs{\style{font-size:25%}{\unicode{x25FA}}}
  \def\NEn{\hskip.5ex\raise.5ex{\style{font-size:25%}{\unicode{x25F9}}}}
  \def\NWn{\raise.5ex{\style{font-size:25%}{\unicode{x25F8}}}}
  \let\SEe=\SEs \let\SWw=\SWs \let\NEe=\NEn \let\NWw=\NWn
}
\def\BlackTriangles{
  \def\SEs{\hskip.5ex\style{font-size:25%}{\unicode{x25E2}}}
  \def\SWs{\style{font-size:25%}{\unicode{x25E3}}}
  \def\NEn{\hskip.5ex\raise.5ex{\style{font-size:25%}{\unicode{x25E5}}}}
  \def\NWn{\raise.5ex{\style{font-size:25%}{\unicode{x25E4}}}}
  \let\SEe=\SEs \let\SWw=\SWs \let\NEe=\NEn \let\NWw=\NWn
}
\def\Paths{
  \def\SEs{
    \style{opacity:.25}{\color{red}{\Rule{1ex}{1ex}{0ex}}}
    \hskip-.5ex\raise.08ex{\style{font-size:25%; opacity:.25}{\color{blue}{\unicode{x25E2}}}}
  }
  \def\SWs{
    \style{opacity:.25}{\color{blue}{\Rule{1ex}{1ex}{0ex}}}
    \hskip-1ex\raise.08ex{\style{font-size:25%; opacity:.25}{\color{red}{\unicode{x25E3}}}}
  }
  \def\NEn{
    \style{opacity:.25}{\color{blue}{\Rule{1ex}{1ex}{0ex}}}
    \hskip-.5ex\raise.58ex{\style{font-size:25%; opacity:.25}{\color{red}{\unicode{x25E5}}}}
  }
  \def\NWn{
    \style{opacity:.25}{\color{red}{\Rule{1ex}{1ex}{0ex}}}
    \hskip-1ex\raise.58ex{\style{font-size:25%; opacity:.25}{\color{blue}{\unicode{x25E4}}}}
  }
  \def\SEe{
    \style{opacity:.25}{\color{blue}{\Rule{1ex}{1ex}{0ex}}}
    \hskip-.5ex\raise.08ex{\style{font-size:25%; opacity:.25}{\color{red}{\unicode{x25E2}}}}
  }
  \def\SWw{
    \style{opacity:.25}{\color{red}{\Rule{1ex}{1ex}{0ex}}}
    \hskip-1ex\raise.08ex{\style{font-size:25%; opacity:.25}{\color{blue}{\unicode{x25E3}}}}
  }
  \def\NEe{
    \style{opacity:.25}{\color{red}{\Rule{1ex}{1ex}{0ex}}}
    \hskip-.5ex\raise.58ex{\style{font-size:25%; opacity:.25}{\color{blue}{\unicode{x25E5}}}}
  }
  \def\NWw{
    \style{opacity:.25}{\color{blue}{\Rule{1ex}{1ex}{0ex}}}
    \hskip-1ex\raise.58ex{\style{font-size:25%; opacity:.25}{\color{red}{\unicode{x25E4}}}}
  }
}
\def\BlueDots{
 \def\SEs{\hskip.5ex\style{font-size:25%}{\unicode{x25FF}}}
  \def\SWs{\color{blue}{\rlap{\hskip.45ex\raise.1ex.}}\style{font-size:25%}{\unicode{x25FA}}}
  \def\NEn{\color{blue}{\rlap{\hskip.1ex\raise.5ex.}}\hskip.5ex\raise.45ex{\style{font-size:25%}{\unicode{x25F9}}}}
  \def\NWn{\raise.5ex{\style{font-size:25%}{\unicode{x25F8}}}}
  \def\SEe{\color{blue}{\rlap{\hskip.45ex\raise.5ex.}}\hskip.5ex\style{font-size:25%}{\unicode{x25FF}}}
  \def\SWw{\style{font-size:25%}{\unicode{x25FA}}}
  \def\NEe{\hskip.5ex\raise.5ex{\style{font-size:25%}{\unicode{x25F9}}}}
  \def\NWw{\color{blue}{\rlap{\hskip.1ex\raise.1ex.}}\raise.5ex{\style{font-size:25%}{\unicode{x25F8}}}}
}
\def\RedDots{
  \def\SEs{\hskip.5ex\style{font-size:25%}{\unicode{x25E2}}}
  \def\SWs{\color{red}{\rlap{\hskip.45ex\raise.1ex.}}\style{font-size:25%}{\unicode{x25E3}}}
  \def\NEn{\color{red}{\rlap{\hskip.1ex\raise.5ex.}}\hskip.5ex\raise.45ex{\style{font-size:25%}{\unicode{x25E5}}}}
  \def\NWn{\raise.5ex{\style{font-size:25%}{\unicode{x25E4}}}}
  \def\SEe{\color{red}{\rlap{\hskip.45ex\raise.5ex.}}\hskip.5ex\style{font-size:25%}{\unicode{x25E2}}}
  \def\SWw{\style{font-size:25%}{\unicode{x25E3}}}
  \def\NEe{\hskip.5ex\raise.5ex{\style{font-size:25%}{\unicode{x25E5}}}}
  \def\NWw{\color{red}{\rlap{\hskip.1ex\raise.1ex.}}\raise.5ex{\style{font-size:25%}{\unicode{x25E4}}}}
}
\def\RedBlueDots{
  \def\SEs{\color{blue}{\rlap{\hskip.1ex\raise.1ex.}}\hskip.5ex\style{font-size:25%}{\unicode{x25E2}}}
  \def\SWs{\color{red}{\rlap{\hskip.45ex\raise.1ex.}}\style{font-size:25%}{\unicode{x25E3}}}
  \def\NEn{\color{red}{\rlap{\hskip.1ex\raise.5ex.}}\hskip.5ex\raise.45ex{\style{font-size:25%}{\unicode{x25E5}}}}
  \def\NWn{\color{blue}{\rlap{\hskip.45ex\raise.5ex.}}\raise.5ex{\style{font-size:25%}{\unicode{x25E4}}}}
  \def\SEe{\color{red}{\rlap{\hskip.45ex\raise.5ex.}}\hskip.5ex\style{font-size:25%}{\unicode{x25E2}}}
  \def\SWw{\color{blue}{\rlap{\hskip.1ex\raise.5ex.}}\style{font-size:25%}{\unicode{x25E3}}}
  \def\NEe{\color{blue}{\rlap{\hskip.45ex\raise.1ex.}}\hskip.5ex\raise.5ex{\style{font-size:25%}{\unicode{x25E5}}}}
  \def\NWw{\color{red}{\rlap{\hskip.1ex\raise.1ex.}}\raise.5ex{\style{font-size:25%}{\unicode{x25E4}}}}
}
\RoundCorners
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%  Create a dragon from the currently saved dragon string starting
%    at the given location on the board, or a big dragon from
%    the last big dragon collections.
%
\def\Dragon#1#2{\Start{#1}{#2}\E \Continue\Db \End}
\def\BigDragon#1#2{\Start{#1}{#2}\E \Bq{}\Bb{}\Ba{} \End}
%
%  Check if there are more letters and call \P if so and \X if not.
%
\def\D#1 #2#3 #4{#4#1 #2#3 #4}
%
%  Place the letter at the current location.
%  Then define \T to determine the new orientation from
%    the current one and the current letter.
%  Perform the orientation command in order to move to the new location.
%
\def\P#1#2#3#4{
  \def\T##1#4#3 ##2##3##4\T{\Place{#1}{#2}##3 ##2{#1}{#2}##2 }
  \T L\E \N\NWw  R\E \S\SWw  L\S \E\NEn  R\S \W\NWn  L\W \S\SEe
     R\W \N\NEe  L\N \W\SWs  R\N \E\SEs  \T
}
%
%  These are the commands to move in the given direction.
%
\def\N#1#2{\def\n##1##2##3{\D{#1}{##1##2##3}}\p\n#2}
\def\E#1#2{\def\n##1##2##3{\D{##1##2##3}{#2}}\p\n#1}
\def\S#1#2{\def\n##1##2##3{\D{#1}{##1##2##3}}\m\n#2}
\def\W#1#2{\def\n##1##2##3{\D{##1##2##3}{#2}}\m\n#1}
%
%  Routines to add or subtract (plus or minus) 1 from
%    a three-digit number, so we can handle 000 to 999.
%    These roll over if they go too far.
%
\def\p#1#2#3#4{
  \def\:##1#4##2##3 ##4#4 ##5##6\:{##5#1#2#3##2}
  \: 01234567890 9 \pp #4 {} \:
}
\def\pp#1#2#3{\p\drop0#2#3#1}
\def\m#1#2#3#4{
  \def\:##1#4##2##3 ##4#4 ##5##6\:{##5#1#2#3##2}
  \: 98765432109 0 \mm #4 {} \:
}
\def\mm#1#2#3{\m\drop9#2#3#1}
\def\drop#1#2#3#4{#4#2#3}
%
%  Start a dragon by placing a marker and creating the \Continue function.
%  End a dragon by continuing with the end marker, cleaning up, and then 
%    placing the board boundary.
%  
\def\Start#1#2#3{\Marker{green}{#1}{#2}\X{#1}{#2}#3\X}
\def\End{\C\EndMarker\Board}
\def\EndMarker#1#2\X{\EndPlace#1}
\def\EndPlace#1#2#3#4{\Marker{red}{#2}{#3}}
%
%  End the current portion of the dragon by defining a continuation 
%    function that records the current location and orientation.
%    Each continuation is done in \text{$...$} so that it gets its own
%    equation environment with its own MAXMACROS and MAXBUFFER space.
%    This lets us do multiple pieces without exceeding the limitations.
%
\def\X#1#2#3#4\X{\def\C##1{\text{$##1{\D{#1}{#2}#3} \P \X$}}\let\Continue=\C}
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%  These functions produce new dragons from old ones.
%  We keep a separate reversed copy so that we don't have
%  to reverse them later.
%
\def\NextDragon{\Next\Da\Db\Dq\Dr}
\def\NextBigDragon{\Next\Ba\Bb\Bq\Br}
\def\Next#1#2#3#4{
  #3\Copy\It #2\Copy\It #1\Copy\It \Define \EndD \tmpA
  #3\Copy\It #4\Copy\It #1\Copy\It \Define \EndD \tmpB
  \let#1=#2 \let#2=\tmpA
  \let#3=#4 \let#4=\tmpB
  \def\tmpA{} \let\tmpB=\tmpA
}
\def\Define#1\EndD#2{\def#2##1{##1 #1}}
\def\Copy#1\It#2\EndD{#2#1\EndD}
%
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%  The initial two dragons (D_0 and D_1) and their reversed versions,
%  and the initial two Big Dragons, based on them.  Big Dragons use
%  \C (\Continue) to do multiple pieces (based on the largest small
%  Dragon that can be processed within the MathJax limits).
%
\def\Da#1{#1 R} \let\Db=\Da
\def\Dq#1{#1 L} \let\Dr=\Dq
%
\def\Ba#1{#1 \C\Da} \def\Bb#1{#1 \C\Db}
\def\Bq#1{#1 \C\Dq} \def\Br#1{#1 \C\Dr}
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
$

$\NextDragon\NextDragon\NextDragon\NextDragon\NextDragon$
$\NextDragon\NextDragon\NextDragon\NextDragon$
$\NextBigDragon\NextBigDragon\NextBigDragon$
$\RoundCorners$
$\BigDragon{113}{095} {132}{132} % Level 14 (9 sec) $
```

Comment: I could not help working on this (when I should have been doing other things), @humn, so I spent three hours coming up with a preliminary solution.  I have posted a version that works up to level 11 without adjusting the MathJax parameters.  I haven't spent any time optimizing it, but just wanted to get something that works.  See the caveat about using CommonHTML output rather than the default HTML-CSS, however.

Comment: Yow! And in a fraction of the coding time it took for my test version.
And an even smaller fraction of the run time 
(9 secs vs 2 mins  for level 11 locally, and that's only after
reducing inner-loop macros to single letters).
Isn't it a gas to make fractals with MathJax?
Ah, stolen moments.
And thanks, of course, for the lessons on HTML options
and on revising macro definitions
($\small\texttt{\Define{}}$),
along with other lessons yet to register.

Comment: I have updated the code to the version that does dragons up to level 19, @humn, and included images (though one seems not to be able to transfer properly I'll have to look into that tomorrow).  See the discussion at the top for some hints as to how it works.

Comment: Absolutely breathtaking, Davide C!!  Both how you got it to work and the fabulous results.
So much to study and just gawk at.
MathJax has never looked so fine, which says a lot
[[slightly more utilitarian example](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28885/the-case-of-the-missing-rebus)].
(In other news, $\small\texttt{\stars{}}$ is knocking on the 65-token barrier.
Latest two approaches came up with that count,
and your current post might secretly be even less.)

Comment: (Extra credit for taking the trouble to render level 19, which so nicely resembles a question mark and whose interior detail is now seen, perhaps for the first time, to be surprisingly beautiful.)

Comment: Thanks for the compliments, @humn.  I also thought that levels 18 and 19 really start to show the fractal nature nicely.  You are right that the interior (or negative space) is as interesting as the positive space.  I would guess that these dragons tile the plane, and so the negative space should be equivalent to the positive space (at least the enclosed pieces).

Comment: Looking forward to your 65-token (or better) result for `\stars`, @humn.  I really want to be able to award you the check mark for that problem, but my 71-token version is the current smallest one your 65 should resolve that.  I haven't done any more work on it.

Comment: It's art, ain't it though?
Here's a quick [experiment](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uDRDB.jpg)
that indicates how level 19 tiles.
(Preparing a 62-token
$\small\texttt{\stars{}}$ post now.
It's almost neat enough to be mistaken for something you'd figure out.
Well, most of it you did.
Thanks for leaving some elbow room, much of it for the sake of clarity no doubt.)

Comment: I've added some new code and images to my answer, @humn.  Thought you might enjoy some decorated dragons (near the bottom of the answer).

Comment: Oooooh, and, ahhhhh.
`\Corners` is classic fractalania.
`\RoundCorners` sweetly verifies non-crossing.
`\TransparentBlocks` reveals a substructure reminiscent of 
[Greek fretwork](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/fretwork)
and the Hilbert curve.
Except for having recreational provenance
these mathterpieces would feel right at home in
[your gallery](http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/professional/art/welcome.html)
or somewhere like [MathJax's portfolio](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/misc/mathjax-in-use.html).
Letters were just clues, and you sure do have more than a clue.

Comment: Never seen a `\Diagonals` version of the standard Dragon,
and couldn't find one on the web just now,
did you make it up?
Suddenly it seems like the crispest way to render these kinds of curves,
and sure makes fantastic mazes.
Interesting how it also camouflages the generating rule
while it's near twin, `\RoundCorners`,
makes the rule about as apparent as possible.
Thank you very much for making the code so easy to play with
as well as for my two new favorite MathJax commands:
$\small\texttt{\style}$ and
$\small\texttt{\Rule}$.

Comment: Yes, I made up `\Diagonals`, @humn.  It was inspired by `\RoundCorners`; I thought about trying to straighten out the wavy lines, and this was the natural way to do that.  I thought it made a nice maze as well.  I was wondering about coloring the two sides of the curve different colors and seeing how that looks.  It should make the maze runs more apparent.  I'm not sure I can do it in MathJax, though.  Glad you are enjoying `\style` and `\Rule`.

Comment: I've added a couple more decoration types, @humn.  The two triangle diagrams were from experiments on the way toward the final `\Paths` image, but I thought they were interesting in their own right.  They both give me the impression of two separate mazes shifted by 45 degrees and superimposed on each other.  The `\Paths` image is my best attempt at coloring the two sides of the dragon line red and blue.  It is not perfect, but it gives a sense of what the maze paths look like, and how they are connected to the outside.  It took a small change to the code to accomplish it.

Comment: PS, not all the styles work week in all output renderers.  Some are best in SVG, others in CommonHTML.  PreviewHTML works good for many, but not all.  Some rely on characters that aren't in the MathJax fonts, so may not work for everyone, and the scaling may not be right for the fonts on your system.  I also had to scale up the page in some cases in order to avoid browser minimum font size limits.  So these newer ones are pretty experimental, and not for prime time.

Comment: A few more images added to the list, @humn.  I had to remove some of the unused ones from the code, since I had exceeded the maximum character count for an answer.  I suppose I should break my answer into two parts if I need to add anything more.

Comment: Dear oh dear, now you can add Stack Exchange's answer limit to
your portfolio of discoveries.
At least the edit history exists,
and I've been saving copies of your works (and code) too, naturally.
They already show at the top of web image searches for "mathjax fractals"
and, again, deserve a better display case than an obscure puzzle.
(Latest $\small\texttt{\stars{}}$ molt =
$\small\texttt{{\N f  x    #2 %        #4#4↵#4    9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0  f    *↵    ↵                 }}$ = 54 tokens + only 1 remaining idea.)

Comment: Your work on `\stars` is astounding, @humn.  The "count-down" approach you have taken is very effective, and quite nice.  I tried my hand at it, but could not do better.  Looking forward to your final version!  The `d e f g` part of your hexadecimal version is clever, but it seems to rely on the fact that the base is a power of 2.  I'm not sure how you will get it to work for base 10.  I see the line above is for base 10, but without the rest of the code, I'm a bit confused.