# I tend to forget things

Tags: riddle, cipher, visual, imgur-maze

I tend to forget things. The only thing that keeps my memories alive is dreaming. During the day I listen to all that is said to me, but in the evening I already forget it. But when I fall asleep all that I learned that day tries to make it to the surface of my conciousness in some enigmatic form. I will tell you my dream. Could you remind me what I forgot about today? Otherwise someone will certainly be mad at me tomorrow.

My drawing skills are not that good, but I will try to draw you some outlines of my dream. To make sure you understand it see the description below:

[image]

The question is: **Could you remind me what I forgot about today?**

Credit (but also a hint):

> *This puzzle was inspired by (the mechanics of) [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/44158/a-thing-of-beauty-is-a-joy-forever) great puzzle by [Ankoganit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/25412/ankoganit).*

Comment: [tag:cipher] surely?

Comment: @lois6b I hope you will get into my dream deep enough to see that this is not a mistake :)

Comment: funny answer. "Black Brown and White" is a song of Big Bill Broonzy. Big Bill means you have forgot to pay! :) (Nice riddle!)

Comment: Small progress: Click on the image, and you get a different image. Use the text in those, and you get more images... Eventually, you need a 'password' and two 'keys', whatever they are.

Comment: @marcoresk It fits so well I'm beginning to regret it is not the intended answer :P

Comment: Does the story have anything to do with the code? Maybe the number of letters in each of the words?

Comment: @Qwerp-Derp The steganography tag is intentionally not there.

Comment: In addition to @boboquack I assume that the passwords / keys you will be getting somehow are (partial) pointers to the next image. I think that the hint from the first picture will somehow give you the password. Would fit to cipher (@loise6b) as well...

Comment: Are you using images from the other puzzle for cracking this?

Comment: @Techidiot All the images used in this puzzle are created exclusively for this puzzle.

Comment: oleslaw- I mean does the images from the referred puzzle hold any meaning here? :)

Comment: @Techidiot No. :) This is entirely separate puzzle. Only the mechanics part (which inspired me to make this puzzle) is kind of similar - this is why I linked it.

Comment: The first image makes me think of ASCII...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I followed the riddle about the dragon and got a result of

> 'drAgN' (capitalised parts were described as larger and the o is the crushed 'hole').

I used a

> Vigenere shift with that as a key using the order of lowercase uppercase and numbers provided by @M Oehm commented on the other answer.

This led to the following page:

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHPzy.png

From there much of the labarynth is visible including the key

> 'd6AQ5'.

I then decrypted the door on the right at the start with that key and the key

> ('dream')

which I got from the hint that the key is

> ('what this is all about')

leading to a result of the page

> (https://i.stack.imgur.com/R657h.png)

From the clue

> (about going to 'his or her door':)

We know

> (that they forgot about going to visit someone.)

From the clues

> (about the shape of the puzzle and about the watch being stuck at 5pm:)

We know

> (that they forgot about having tea with someone because 5pm is tea time and the puzzle is in a 'T' shape.)

From the clues

> (about it being somwhere 'near you and my ant':)

We can get the word

> ('aunt'(by adding 'u' to 'ant'))

Putting it all together, we can work out that they have forgotten about their plans to

> have tea with their aunt.

Comment: That's brilliant! The labyrinth continues with `ZKFwX` and even further.

Comment: How did you get to that?

Comment: The codes on floor tiles are just connections that you can enter straight away: [ZKFwX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKFwX.png), [Dldtx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dldtx.png), [opkOi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opkOi.png).

Comment: I think thats the whole of the answer. Please tell me if I need more detail on what was forgotten

Comment: You are almost there. There are clues about who you are supposed to meet. Filling this detail it is all the answer I expect :)

Comment: They need to have tea with their aunt. Thanks for adding spoiler tags by the way.

Comment: Please add more detailed reasoning for why you think the final answer is correct (which is correct by the way).

Answer (score 2):

### Partial answer

First, click on the image in the question. Hidden behind what you can actually see in the question is a quite different Stack.Imgur image:

> [image]

This image contains two five-character codes. Each of these yields a Stack.Imgur image of its own:

> [image] [image]

Finally, each one of these two images leads to yet another Stack.Imgur image:

> [image] [image]

Putting together all the text from these images:

> 1. There is some ordering in my head. It starts with an 'a' goes through an 'A' and ends with a '9'.
>  2. I see a door ahead. It is decorated by a dragon carved in the wood. It is crushing a small circle and it grows bigger when I look at its middle and its tail.
>  3. The door ahead reminded me that the thing I forgot about was that someone wanted me to be at his or her door. Tomorrow.
>  4. The door has a panel with numbers and letters. But what is the correct code?
>  5. Door is locked with two keys. I have to find them.

From clue 1, I think we should be looking for another Stack.Imgur image with a code of the form `a?A?9`. Clue 2 might be telling us something about the same code (perhaps "small circle" = `o`?) Clue 4 could again refer to the same code, or perhaps a different one since clue 5 seems to tell us that there are two different codes.

Comment: I think the clue in the first room means that the possible characters of imgur addresses are ordered `a-zA-Z0-9`; we might need that ordering when we find numerical clues. I've tried "drAgN" - a dragon that crushes its circle and whose letters at the middle and tail are capital - but that didn't work, of course. I think such literal clues hard to pull off anyway, because the author doesn't have control over the address. As far as I can see, the images have no metadata or hidden text that can be revealed with a flood fill.

Comment: As to the "drAgN" thing - sometimes you don't have control, but you get lucky to get an address like this :) (or not the adress but its part)

Comment: Well, now that I see how the keys work I can also see that you can have several shots: Upload both the door and its destination _n_ times and you get _n_  × _n_ possible outcomes. That's clever.