# From the death to the fresh beginning - A treasure hunt

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge, visual, geography, treasure-hunt

Shortly after your mentor's passing, you received an envelope along with the following note:

> My Dear Disciple,
>
> I am afraid my time to leave this world has come but don't let it bother you, for I have already lived a long and fulfilled life. As a final goodbye and an honour to all the precious moments we spent crafting and solving puzzles together, I have spent these last few months orchestrating this treasure-hunt just for you.
>
> The key and the chest have been sent to my most faithful friend overseas and are now being kept/ buried in different locations. Every piece of paper in this envelope has all the clues you need to find the specific location of both the key and the chest.
>
> This treasure is not only my final gift to you but also to your family. The fortune inside is more than enough to lay a foundation of a good life for your children. Let this treasure be the legacy that will pass on to their generation and the beginning of their endless opportunity that is to come.
>
> Love,
> Your Mentor

Inside the envelope are three zipper bags with a label attached; each bags contain pieces of paper with clues. One of the papers has been torn up to smaller pieces.

---

Here are all the pieces of paper found in each bags:

`#`

[image]

`⌂⌂⌂, ⚑`

[image]

`⌂, ⌂⌂⌂, ⚑`

[image]     [image]

```
Text:
Kb iochy uv bawmoj
```

**Find the key and the chest.**

---

Hint:

> - The fish lost his toque blanche he usually wears.
> - the fish = ⚑, cardinal directions = ⌂⌂⌂

Hint II (Hoping this will make the puzzle less of fumbling in the vast dark room.):

> - ⚑ = country, ⌂⌂⌂ = city/ town/ village
> - Mentor's favourite land is where the potatoes turn french. (This hint bypasses the fish by narrowing it down to a province)

Hint III:

> [image]

Hint IV:

> We’ve already established what country and province the key and chest would be in from @OmegaKrypton's answer. The next step should be finding out what ⌂⌂⌂s each cardinal direction represents.

**Hint V:**

> - Save every image and inspect closely what distinguishes the white from brown paper.
> - Google Maps is your friend.
> - Although the last two papers possess the same quality as the second paper, they're not meant to be used with the same reference.
> - Observe back and forth between all the pieces of paper and find a relation between them.

Comment: nice puzzle +1, is there anything I got wrong so far? Thanks!

Comment: Might be looking too deeply, but if you zoom in the knife looks like there might be words on it. But the res is too low to be sure.

Comment: It says "stainless steel".

Comment: The rectangular icon in the third picture looks like some kind of cassette player. Or at least it has the voicemail symbol on it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The key and treasure chest are ...

> ... hidden in **Martinikerk, Koudum** and in a playing ground in **Pastorijstrjitte, Oudega**, both towns in the province of Friesland, the Netherlands.

The directions refer to ...

> ... the region around Hindeloopen in Friesland:
>
>  [image: A part of western Friesland]
>  (Click to [see it in Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/@52.9271947,5.538339,12z).)
>
>  The rebus for N shows an incon for "undo" or "go back" and the back is the **hind** part; the letter **e**; a **loop** and the letter **n**. (And you can probably work out the second rebus in Hint III.) **Hindeloopen** is a small town on the IJsselmeer.
>
>  A few kilometres to the east is **It Heidenskip** and the fast-forward button in the E rebus can mean "skip". **Workum** (the map above shows the Frisian name Warkum) is to the north of both and the N rebus begins with W, but I'm not sure how the cog can mean something like "ark". The S rebus is completely covered, but I'm sure it is **Koudum**.

The paper with the diamond, circle and red X ...

> ... uses these four places as reference for the diamond, as Kami V found out. We can scale and turn that paper and overlay in on a map – thankfully, the image background is transparent. In the configuration below, the circle lines up with the ring road around Sneek:
>
>  [image: A diamond and circle in Friesland]
>
>  The X then marks the village of [Oudega](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oudega,_S%C3%BAdwest-Frysl%C3%A2n)

The message on the last sheet of paper ...

> ... seems to require a key. One poular cipher with a key is the Vigenère cipher. There is a key symbol on the southern tip of the diamond at **Koudom**. Using that as key, the message decodes to:
>
>   **An oliv**y uv bawmoj
>
>  (Only the bold parts have been decrypted, the rest is left as is.) That could be the start to a sentence, perhaps "an olive". To cut a long story short: I found the intended message more or less by accident, but the OP pointed me towards the intended solution, which I'll disclose now as if it were my own.
>
>    [image: tape to key]
>
>  The piece of paper shows a diamond, which not only relates to the locations of the four towns, but also to the positions of the masking tape on the torn sheet. That sheet had the rebuses for the four towns:
>
>    [image]
>
>  W = Hindeloopen
>  S = **Koudum**
>  **N** = Work**um**
>  E = **It Heiden**skip
>
>  The bold parts are covered by tape. (The cassette tape symbol in the clipping with the encrypted message is supposed to point towards the tapes. I didn't see that, because I failed to associate the cassette tape with the sticky tape.) The bold parts are also arranged in a diamond shape and the arrows point to the N, E and S parts, which yield the Vigenère key "koudum um it heiden" and the plain text:
>
>  **An olive in itself**

The key ...

> ... is hidden in Koudum. (Kami V saw that: The key symbol is in Koudum's place in the diamond.) The decoded message, "An olive in itself" refers to the exact location of the key in Koudum.
>
>    [image]
>    [image]
>
>  At the centre of Koudum is Martinikerk, the church of St Martin's. The church has an oval, grassy churchyard surrounding it, which looks like an olive on a map. And, of course, a Martini is usually served with an olive "in itself". The key is hidden in **Martinikerk in Koudum**.

The clipping with the volcano sketch ...

> ... has some sublte nuances of transparency / blackness: There are thin, dark lines and broader, slightly brigher lines. I've increased the brightness to make them stand out better:
>
>   [image]
>
>  This piece of paper can be overlaid over the torn paper:
>
>  [image]
>
>  The thick lines are all on the masking tape, perhaps indicating that it is difficult to write there with a felt tip. The folds in the tape line up nicely with the right flank of the volcano and the left bit of shore. Now look at the tears, which I have highlighted.

The treasure chest ...

> ... is hidden in Oudega. The tears in the torn papers are streets in Oudega. More precisely, the tear pattern match with the street map near Pastorijstrjitte:
>
>   [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]
>
>  The X in the overlain volcano map points to a sandpit in a playing ground. So the treasure chest is buried in the sandpit in a **playing ground in Pastorijstrjitte in Oudega**.

Comment: The decrypted message is indeed correct. Great job on the work-around! But can you also solve it by the intended process? Because, it might give you a clue on what to do with the volcano paper (slightly similar method). **HINT:** Did you notice that the arrangement of the arrows in the last paper are suspiciously similar to another detail in the puzzle? Maybe that's the reference you're supposed to overlay it with. And for the cassette symbol, what does it alternatively called—like a very short word of it?

Comment: Really? I didn't expect that. I know that I can overlay the tape paper on the diamond sketch without rotating. The actual key I used is "Koudum um It Heide(nskip)", so I'm confused about where the "um" comes from. The phrase might mean "to K via IH", but "um" doesn't seem to ba a Dutch word. And a music cassette is a tape ot an MC. Hmmm.

Comment: The arrows are not pointing at the towns, they refer to a position of something else *that’s arranged like a shape of diamond* indicated by the symbol at [the starting point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassette_tape). Can you see it :)

Comment: *See OmegaKrypton’s first spoiler block for a visual reference*: Interpret the whole thing as rot13(Sbyybjvat nybat gur "gncr" nppbeqvat gb gur neebj qverpgvba jvyy tvir lbh gur "xrl": XBHQHZHZVGURVQRA) Sorry for my wording earlier.

Comment: Oh! I see it now. I didn't associate one kind of a thing with the other. (But I did wonder why the torn paper was covered in tape.)

Comment: The **X** only marks the **treasure chest** and the **red key** only marks **the key**. KamiV is right that the key resides at Koudum and you’ve found that the chest resides at Oudega. So, the last step is to look at the map of those two locations. Look closely at the map of Koudum and I can assure you that the plaintext will suddenly make more sense and the tear lines up with the roads at Oudega perfectly (I suggest that you move the pieces away from each other a little to form a road-like shape and you’ll see it more clearly) To save you time: [:)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoklt.png).

Comment: Okay, I'm shaken (but not stirred) that I have been on the wrong track again ... `:)`

Comment: I see what you did there :) You were also right that the key is with mentor’s friend. There’s a little hint in the flavour text: “**faithful** friend”. Everything's correct now! Is it alright if I edit your post to add some more visual aids or should I give them to you directly here in the comment so you can edit it in yourself?

Comment: I'm sure I have missed many clues and I appreciate that you want to resolve them. (For example, I still don't know what the link to the Netherlands / Friesland and the knife-bearing red herring is.) You could write a separate [wrap-up answer like this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/52073/9860), but if you just want to edit in the missing pieces, I'm fine with that. (Perhaps you could mark your own additions with OP or with your name.)

Comment: The puzzle has some very nice elements. It's a pity that it didn't get much attention.  This seems like a good puzzle to solve in a team -- someone in the team would probably have seen the things I've missed or got wrong.

Comment: I just have to say... WOW both to the question AND the answer! Wow!! :D Inspiring!

Answer (score 7):

**Partial:**

`#`

**Shredded pieces of paper:**

> I found this by reassembling them:
> [image: shredded assembled]
> The green numbers are how I will label the covered areas of the tapes

:: Upper image

> knife + fish? might be a rebus or a hint on how to decipher some messages
>  Found the fish at: [here](http://firsttechchallenge.blogspot.com/2013/07/) and [**luckily here (sigh)**](http://challenge712.rssing.com/chan-10888907/all_p8.html), which at nearly the bottom of the website show that the fish is a **red herring :( BEWARE...**
>  By the way, this might help... [red herring + knife... but IS THIS A RED HERRING???](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B075VZMGFW)

- The fish:

  > is a red herring with a knife with the words "stainless steel" as suggested by @MOehm in the comments. From the hint perhaps the fish is a cook, due to the *toque blanche*, which is the white hat chefs wear

:: Lower image

- Area covered by tape *ii* is

  > clearly the remaining part of the letter N, therefor the letters on the LHS are W, S, N, and E, the **four directions**
- West:

  > Hind (undo icon) + e + loop (loop/ refresh icon) + n = **Hindeloopen** credits @MOehm
- East:

  > ??? + skip (fast-forward icon) = **It Heidenskip** credits @MOehm
- North:

  > W + ??? + ??? = **Warkum** credits @MOehm

`⌂⌂⌂, ⚑ and ⌂, ⌂⌂⌂, ⚑`

**The cross:**

> Perhaps the cross in `⌂⌂⌂, ⚑` is referring to the cross in `⌂, ⌂⌂⌂, ⚑`, i.e. the mid-hill near a river area is between the diamond and the circle. This should also be where the key/ chest is

**Second piece of paper**

> Perhaps this? [Lauwers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lauwers)

**Text in last piece of paper**

> Most possible: (rot4): Of msglc yz feaqsn

---

HINTS:

- H2:

  > mentor's fav. land = french potato = French Fries --> **FRIESLAND, NETHERLANDS**?
- H3:

  > rebus for west: Hind (deer?) + e + loo (toilet) + pen (a pen...) = Hindeloopen

Comment: The cipher is incorrect. You’re right to be skeptical about the rot13(erq ureevat) but your interpretation is off the mark. The letters on the left of :: lower image are indeed four directions.

Comment: “Stainless steel” is unimportant otherwise it would be a very mean thing to do—making a clue so small to the point of being unreadable. The fish is not necessary needed to solve the puzzle but it’s also a valid clue that if solved, make the puzzle a little more easier. Because, If you know the ⌂⌂⌂ then the ⚑ is not necessary needed anymore but it’s much more easier to know the ⚑ first and then find the ⌂⌂⌂ in it.

Comment: Your take on "mentor's favourite *land*" is very very close but, unlike the fish, It doesn’t refer to a country. You got all the words in there, the tail and the head. Just have to connect it.

Comment: `H2:` is correct now.

Comment: am i correct on the river? @Chrone Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

(Partial)

I'll try to explain the meaning of the diamond and the circle:

> As @MOehm and @OmegaKrypton pointed out, the cardinal letters W,E,S,N refer to four places in Netherlands. Those four places, when connected on the map, form the following:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nxz4e.png

> I suppose the Hegemer Mar is the circle, and between them, lies the X, Gaastmeer. Lastly, according to the drawing we were provided with, I'd say the key rests at the bottom of the diamond, in Koudum.

Comment: Ha! That's a good observation, but I think the scale is a bit off. Playing with your idea a bit, I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkfRW.png), which would place the X at [Oudega](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oudega,_S%C3%BAdwest-Frysl%C3%A2n). I've no idea what I should make of the other piece of paper with an X, though. I've also thoght about Koudum as key, but in [another way](http://rumkin.com/tools/cipher/vigenere.php), but it only gets me halfway there. Maybe there's a connection with note with the encrypted text?

Comment: @MOehm That’s spot on! Regarding the note with the encrypted text, maybe the new hint I’ve added can help you.