# Finish the beautiful, ten story tower

Tags: mathematics, visual, steganography

A mathematician has commissioned you to build a beautiful tower, ten stories tall, and it's almost complete!
Here are the number of bricks in each level, and the layout of the steel girders.
Exactly how many bricks do the incomplete levels require and why?
*Note: Replace each '?' with a single digit.

[image: numbers]

Bonus Hidden Beauty Challenge (optional):
Without changing any integer values or the floor they are on, turn the tower into gold (9). (multiple essentially equivalent solutions).

Text version:

- 30
- 200003000
- 420000
- 1100
- ?1003010
- 300002
- 1000
- ??000000
- 100000
- 30

Hint:

> No complicated math required. Look for a simple, logical, beautiful solution. The girders are a hint.

Hint 2:.

> This is not a sequence or cipher. @jlee found one thing. Where are the rest?

Comment: Are rot13(gur pbybef bs gur obeqref) significant?

Comment: @EdMurphy Yes, I updated the text to that effect.

Comment: Maybe I'm odd, but this is in my top 3 favorite puzzles I've made so far, even though it's a simple concept.  I hope everyone at least gives it a try. Look for an obviously correct answer that explains all aspects of the puzzle.

Comment: Something just clicked. But i need to figure out one more thing!

Comment: Does the gray vs black girder color have any significance? Or is that just an image artifact?

Comment: @jlee Yes, there are 2 colors to differentiate them. Any other differences or nuances of the girders is irrelevant. The color choice is irrelevant.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The missing levels require ...

> ... **41 003 010** and **40 000 000** bricks.
>
>  With these numbers, the total sum of all bricks in the tower is 281 828 172, which are the first nine decimal digits of **Euler's number** e = 2.718281828459..., read from right to left.
>
>  The sum of the digits on each level are the digits of π = 3.141592653..., read from bottom to top. (I hadn't realised this until [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463/jlee) pointed it out.)
>  {Op edit: This is equivalent to *right*-aligning the numbers and then summing the *columns* from *right* to left to construct a number, and summing the *rows* from *bottom* to top to construct a number. This insight is important for the later  bonus challenge). Also note that finding one # without the other does not lead to a unique solution.}
>
>  Here's the complete tower with the zeros left out for clarity:
>
> ```
>                · · · · · · · 3 ·    3
>                2 · · · · 3 · · ·    5
>                · · · 4 2 · · · ·    6
>                · · · · · 1 1 · ·    2
>                · 4 1 · · 3 · 1 ·    9
>                · · · 3 · · · · 2    5
>                · · · · · 1 · · ·    1
>                · 4 · · · · · · ·    4
>                · · · 1 · · · · ·    1
>                · · · · · · · 3 ·    3
>
>
>                2 8 1 8 2 8 1 7 2
> ```

That was hinted at ...

> ... by the fact that a mathematician had commissioned the tower. [Leonhard Euler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonhard_Euler) was a famous mathematician. And [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula), which uses both *e* and *π* is considered to be very beautiful by some, also in [our circles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/44158/a-thing-of-beauty-is-a-joy-forever).
>
>  The grey girders, when flipped horizontally, look like an **e**, so the digits of e must be read right to left.. When flipped vertically, they look like a **π**, so π must be read from bottom to top.

Bonus challenge: A golden tower ...

> ... is related to the first nine digits of the [**golden ratio**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio) *φ* = 1.61803398874..., so we must arrange the existing digits horizontally to get **161 803 398**, whose digit sum is also 39. But I don't see how.

Op Edit: (self-completing as the difficulty level of the bonus challenge was beyond the scope of the main puzzle.)

> We have seen that if we align the digits to the *right*:
>  The sums of the *columns* from *right* to left form the beautiful number *e*.
>  The sums of the *rows* from *bottom* to top form the beautiful number *pi*.

So how can we form a third beautiful number without changing any integer values or the floor they are on?

> Well, we were asked to make a *golden* tower, not a *nedlog* one, so let's align the digits to the **left** and sum *left* to right!
>  But we face a problem! The left digits sum to 26, and we are looking for the first 9 digits of phi, so it should begin with 1 or 16.
>  The secret here is to notice that we can left-pad zeros to the numbers; this will change their left alignment but not their integer values!
>  (Or you could just stagger them with whitespace, for the same result)...

> ```
>  000000030        | 3
>  0200003000       | 5
>  0000000420000    | 6
>  00000001100      | 2
>  041003010        | 9
>  000300002        | 5
>  0001000          | 1
>  00040000000      | 4
>  100000           | 1
>  0000000030       | 3
>  _____________
>  1618033980000
> ```
>
> *Note that due to similar rows with a sole 1 or 3, a few trivial variants are possible by swapping similar rows, but they are essentially equivalent constructions)*

> The rows still add up to **pi**, the right-aligned digits still add up to **e**, and now the left-aligned rows add up to
>  1618033980000, which if we insert the required decimal, is 1.618033980000, which is mathematically equal to 1.61803398, the first nine digits of the **golden ratio**, as desired.
>  Thus our golden tower, concealing all three beautiful numbers, is complete!

Comment: @MOehm In the hope that you don't mind, I tweaked the puzzle to eliminate the potential ambiguity. It should not affect your corrected answer; just needed to factor in the girder orientation.

Comment: Also I just realized what you did by adding a 'depth dimension'. That's very clever... and cheating : ) (and far too easy). The bonus should be solved in 2D like the others.

Comment: Can you rot13(ercynpr tbyq jvgu cynfgvp? Hasbeghangryl, fvyire qbrfa'g jbex, nf gur qvtvg fhz whzcf sebz 33 gb 40.)

Comment: @Amoz: Ah, I see what you mean and now I understand why the e is flipped. Yes, my idea was to reposition the digits for the gold tower in the third dimension. Aren't we constantly told that we should broaden our view when we can't solve a problem? `:)` And of course I don't mind that you made a slight modification to your puzzle.

Comment: rot13(Cuv vf gur pbeerpg inyhr, ohg sbe gur obahf V jnf ybbxvat sbe na ryrtnag fbyhgvba va gur fnzr fcvevg nf gur pheerag qrfvta (ahzoref ner rvgure ubevmbagny be iregvpny-ab 3Q be qvntbanyf, rgp.). Fvapr gur sybbef ner abg crezvggrq gb punatr, vg fubhyq or pyrne gung gur gnfx vf gb yrnir cv nybar, naq "ghea r vagb tbyq".) @EdMurphy

Comment: @MOehm Excellent, now you stand a fighting chance at the bonus. If you prefer to skip it just let me know and I can close this out with a green check!

Comment: I'm going to try my hand at the bonus., but I don't think I can do it without either ignoring the zeros or pushing them outside the tower ("golden Jenga tower"). If I don't I've got at least a 2 on either end, but I need a 1.

Comment: If you don't want to waste the bonus puzzle, you could also post it as a new question. I'm stuck on the bonus part, but I can see why you think of this puzzle as one of your favourites.