# A Victorious Figure

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

**What's the 15-letter answer I'm looking for?**

---

[image]

---

Hint 1a

> [image]

Hint 1b

> [image] 
>  **Note:** It's not a sign (like o or 0) just suppose to look like a little circle/point.

Hint 2 (a bit stronger)

> "o" - "o"

Comment: Is the answer clearly and obviously the only correct one? Or provide some sort of check sum? I assume it's not Lb or Lv?

Comment: @Amoz I'd say it is. Everything is contained within the puzzle. Chengarda found the first part. The second part (which is knowledge based) is hard to see but once spotted it will make sense (taking into account the "approximately-sign" aswell.)

Comment: @Amoz No, that doesn't ring any bell. Maybe you can rot13 what you mean?

Comment: Yes 15 letters exactly

Comment: Ok. But no, that's on the wrong track. No people involved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be a:

> GOLDEN RECTANGLE?

As noted by @Chengarda,

> connecting red squares with straight lines when not blocked by black squares spells out Au, the chemical symbol for gold: (borrowed picture for completeness, credit @Chengarda)
>  [image: Au]

> The grid is conspicuously sized 10x16 when 10x14 would have sufficed. This ratio, 10/16, equals 1.6,or ~1.6180333..., the **gold**en ratio, phi (also a hidden value in a certain [tower](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/117523/finish-the-beautiful-ten-story-tower)).

So it seems the answer may have something to do with

> phi.

> Phi itself could be a 'victorious figure'; according to Mario Livio:
>  "...it is probably fair to say that the Golden Ratio has inspired thinkers of all disciplines like no other number in the history of mathematics."

> Three mathematicians strongly associated with Phi are Leonardo Bonacci, Leonardo da Vinci, and Michael Maestlin. Due to their profound impacts on math and science, any of these figures could be referred to as 'victorious' (or 'champions'). All are 15 letters.

> Other associated terms include 'golden rectangle' (what this actually almost is), 'the golden spiral' and 'Fibonacci spiral', all 15 letters but probably only by coincidence. Any of these could be 'victorious' as they are considered gold standards in art and design.

Final guess:

> GOLDEN RECTANGLE as it fits the actual literal shape. If we interpret the 'Au in box' as a 'Rectangle (figure) *made* of gold' (rather than *related* to gold), then this answer fits perfectly, rather than tenuously. I'd been mostly thrown when I assumed 'figure' meant we needed to find a person, and spent the last week on Wikipedia scouring articles on the golden rectangle and golden ratio looking for a link to a person famous in war, sports, or science.

Comment: That was it! You got the intended answer. And your "update" is exactly how I wanted it to be interpreted. Also, I chose those numbers intentionally so that it would be more clear what I was looking for (although not easy to detect)

Comment: So are the black squares just to guide the lines joining the reds? They have no other purpose?

Comment: @Stiv Yes exactly, just to function as "blockages". All reds should connect to every red possible (where there's no black in their way)

Answer (score 1):

Hmm I found that if I:

> Join the red squares with lines where they are not blocked by black
>  squares, it seems to spell out Au:
>
>  [image]
>
>  Au is the chemical symbol for Gold, so maybe the answer is "Gold Medal
>  Winner" - 15 letters, a victorious figure?

Comment: This is all I've ever found too - I have no idea what to do with the black squares...

Comment: You got that part right. Rot13(Gur oynpx fdhnerf jrer bayl gurer gb oybpx gur yvarf pbaarpgvat gur erqf, juvpu lbh svtherq bhg.)  But the answer I'm looking for is different than yours. The second part of the puzzle is more knowledge based, nothing complicated but still some knowledge is required.